# Large listboxes not populating well when scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, scroll

I have a fairly large listbox control in my app. It's about... say 200 or so elements big. When I scroll down really quickly, I tend to see the entire contents of the listbox disappear, and then I have to reload the page to see the contents again.

Is this a known issue? And if so, is there a possible workaround? For my contingency plan, I'm going to limit the size of the listbox to say... 100. But I'd like to not do this if I can.

Comment: use longlistselector instead of the standard listbox

Comment: Ah but my listbox is sort of unordered. it's ordered by 'popularity'. so I could do this, but I'd have to put categories for top 50, and top 100, etc. which feels a bit strange to me

Comment: longlistselector has a flat mode, in which there is no grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the LongListSelector, which is optimized for this scenario: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector(v=vs.105).aspx